# remove opening and closing animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a css of Pacman eating animation in css. How can I remove the opening and closing animation and make the mouth to remain always open

```css
.loader{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;height:60px;width:160px;margin:0;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);transform:translate(-50%,-50%)}
.circles{position:absolute;left:-5px;top:0;height:60px;width:180px}
.circles span{position:absolute;top:25px;height:12px;width:12px;border-radius:12px;background-color:grey}
.circles span.one{right:80px}
.circles span.two{right:40px}
.circles span.three{right:0px}
.circles{-webkit-animation:animcircles 0.5s infinite linear;animation:animcircles 0.5s infinite linear}
@-webkit-keyframes animcircles{0%{-webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px);transform:translate(0px,0px)}100%{-webkit-transform:translate(-40px,0px);transform:translate(-40px,0px)}}
@keyframes animcircles{0%{-webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px);transform:translate(0px,0px)}100%{-webkit-transform:translate(-40px,0px);transform:translate(-40px,0px)}}
.pacman{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;height:60px;width:60px}
.pacman .eye{position:absolute;top:10px;left:30px;height:7px;width:7px;border-radius:7px;background-color:#1C163A}
.pacman span{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:60px;width:60px}
.pacman span::before{content:"";position:absolute;left:0;height:30px;width:60px;background-color:yellow} 
.pacman .top::before{top:0;border-radius:60px 60px 0px 0px}
.pacman .bottom::before{bottom:0;border-radius:0px 0px 60px 60px}
.pacman .left::before{bottom:0;height:60px;width:30px;border-radius:60px 0px 0px 60px}
.pacman .top{-webkit-animation:animtop 0.5s infinite;animation:animtop 0.5s infinite}
@-webkit-keyframes animtop{0%,100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg)}50%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg)}}
@keyframes animtop{0%,100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg)}50%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg)}}
.pacman .bottom{-webkit-animation:animbottom 0.5s infinite;animation:animbottom 0.5s infinite}
@-webkit-keyframes animbottom{0%,100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg)}50%{-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg)}}
@keyframes animbottom{0%,100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg)}50%{-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg)}}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="circles">
    <span class="one"></span>
    <span class="two"></span>
    <span class="three"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="pacman">
    <span class="top"></span>
    <span class="bottom"></span>
    <span class="left"></span>
    <div class="eye"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the two css classes that adds the animation

`.pacman .top` and `.pacman .bottom` change to:

```
.pacman .bottom{
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg)
}
.pacman .top{
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg)
}
```

so it looks like this:

```css
.loader{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;height:60px;width:160px;margin:0;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);transform:translate(-50%,-50%)}
.circles{position:absolute;left:-5px;top:0;height:60px;width:180px}
.circles span{position:absolute;top:25px;height:12px;width:12px;border-radius:12px;background-color:grey}
.circles span.one{right:80px}
.circles span.two{right:40px}
.circles span.three{right:0px}
.circles{-webkit-animation:animcircles 0.5s infinite linear;animation:animcircles 0.5s infinite linear}
@-webkit-keyframes animcircles{0%{-webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px);transform:translate(0px,0px)}100%{-webkit-transform:translate(-40px,0px);transform:translate(-40px,0px)}}
@keyframes animcircles{0%{-webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px);transform:translate(0px,0px)}100%{-webkit-transform:translate(-40px,0px);transform:translate(-40px,0px)}}
.pacman{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;height:60px;width:60px}
.pacman .eye{position:absolute;top:10px;left:30px;height:7px;width:7px;border-radius:7px;background-color:#1C163A}
.pacman span{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:60px;width:60px}
.pacman span::before{content:"";position:absolute;left:0;height:30px;width:60px;background-color:yellow} 
.pacman .top::before{top:0;border-radius:60px 60px 0px 0px}
.pacman .bottom::before{bottom:0;border-radius:0px 0px 60px 60px}
.pacman .left::before{bottom:0;height:60px;width:30px;border-radius:60px 0px 0px 60px}

.pacman .bottom{-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg)}
.pacman .top{-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg)}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="circles">
    <span class="one"></span>
    <span class="two"></span>
    <span class="three"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="pacman">
    <span class="top"></span>
    <span class="bottom"></span>
    <span class="left"></span>
    <div class="eye"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's really rocks....thanks for the awesome reply, can u do me one more help, right now if you observe in first look it seems those three dotts are shifted from left to right in each interval.....how can we make it better and smooth. ...is there any way in which the the balls that are entering into the mouth makes it **fadeoff** and the new balls originating at the right **fadesin**

Comment: you could add some animation with `opacity` to the `.one` and `.three`

Comment: I have added `.circles span.one{right:80px; opacity:0.999}
.circles span.two{right:40px}
.circles span.three{right:0px; opacity:0.999}` but seems not working

Comment: you need to setup up keyframes like this `@keyframes fade-in{ 0%{opacity: 0} 100%{opacity: 1} }` and then use that animation something like this
`.one {animation:fade-in 0.5s infinite linear; animation-direction: alternate;}
.three{animation:fade-in 0.5s infinite linear}`

Comment: i have not tested it, you can try and use `ms` instead of `s`that should be more precise. `animation:fade-in 500ms`

Answer (score 1):

```css
.loader{position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; height:60px; width:160px; margin:0; -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%); transform:translate(-50%,-50%) }
.circles{position:absolute; left:-5px; top:0; height:60px; width:180px }
.circles span{position:absolute; top:25px; height:12px; width:12px; border-radius:12px; background-color:grey }
.circles span.one{right:80px }
.circles span.two{right:40px }
.circles span.three{right:0px }
.circles{-webkit-animation:animcircles 0.5s infinite linear; animation:animcircles 0.5s infinite linear }
@-webkit-keyframes animcircles{0%{-webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px); transform:translate(0px,0px) } 100%{-webkit-transform:translate(-40px,0px); transform:translate(-40px,0px) } }
@keyframes animcircles{0% {-webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px); transform:translate(0px,0px) } 100% {-webkit-transform:translate(-40px,0px); transform:translate(-40px,0px) } }
.pacman{position:absolute; left:0; top:0; height:60px; width:60px }
.pacman .eye{position:absolute; top:10px; left:30px; height:7px; width:7px; border-radius:7px; background-color:#1C163A }
.pacman span{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:60px; width:60px }
.pacman span::before{content:""; position:absolute; left:0; height:30px; width:60px; background-color:yellow }
.pacman .top::before{top:0; border-radius:60px 60px 0px 0px }
.pacman .bottom::before{bottom:0; border-radius:0px 0px 60px 60px }
.pacman .left::before{bottom:0; height:60px; width:30px; border-radius:60px 0px 0px 60px}
.pacman .top{transform: rotate( -45deg );}
.pacman .bottom{transform: rotate( 45deg );}
```

```html
  <div class="loader">
  <div class="circles">
    <span class="one"></span>
    <span class="two"></span>
    <span class="three"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="pacman">
    <span class="top"></span>
    <span class="bottom"></span>
    <span class="left"></span>
    <div class="eye"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```